# log4j - writing all output into a file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, spring-boot

I want to write my all output to a file. I have a following configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Log4j writes everything to the console, but it writes only some of it to the file. I want it to write to the file the same output that it writes to the console. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to define log4j2.xml like this;

```
<Configuration status="WARN">

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-7level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="/var/tmp/logs/app.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-7level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="audit" />
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="audit" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: How to use this file? Where in my java project should I write that I use it?

Comment: you can write it at src.

Comment: I changed in my log4j.properties file "debug" to "trace" and it didn't work.

Comment: What src? What do you mean?

Comment: You can create a new file log4j2.xml at src folder of your project.

Comment: Don't know why, but I am using the same thing. BTW which jars are you using?

Comment: It's spring boot with maven. I use one jar which is my application. I use 1.2.17 version of log4j.